# Azure Function app fails on .NET 7 - System.ComponentModel is missing

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I created Azure Functions App through Rider and added class that inherits from `FunctionsStartup` to configure DI. When I launch debugging - it fails (please see output below). But changing target framework to .NET 6 fixes my app without any additional changes. How do I run my app on .NET 7? I can't figure out if this missing package should come out of box, or I should install it myself (there is no System.ComponentModel 7.0.0 in Nuget).

System.ComponentModel 4.3.1 does not work.

> C:\Users\Asus.AzureToolsForIntelliJ\AzureFunctionsCoreTools\v4\4.40.0\func.exe
> host start --pause-on-error
>
> Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit
> hash: N/A  (64-bit) Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667
>
> [2023-06-22T13:33:53.116Z] Found
> C:\Users\Asus\Source\Repos\COMPANY\Sources\COMPANY.Functions.Emails\COMPANY.Functions.Emails.csproj.
> Using for  user secrets file configuration. [2023-06-22T13:33:54.755Z]
> Error configuring services in an external startup class.
> [2023-06-22T13:33:54.756Z] Error configuring services in an external
> startup class. COMPANY.Functions.Emails: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Syst em.ComponentModel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified. [2023-06-22T13:33:55.322Z] A host error has occurred during
> startup operation '8cfbbf94-d585-4f40-a284-56fd665093d8'.
> [2023-06-22T13:33:55.323Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error
> configuring services in an external startup class.
> COMPANY.Functions.Emails: Could  not load file or assembly
> 'System.ComponentModel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the fil e
> specified. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider') Press any key
> to continue....[2023-06-22T13:33:56.407Z] Error configuring services
> in an external startup class. [2023-06-22T13:33:56.408Z] Error
> configuring services in an external startup class.
> COMPANY.Functions.Emails: Could not load file or assembly 'Syst
> em.ComponentModel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified. [2023-06-22T13:33:56.424Z] A host error has occurred during
> startup operation 'd4774568-11f7-4823-a195-772d543c35e8'.
> [2023-06-22T13:33:56.425Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Error
> configuring services in an external startup class.
> COMPANY.Functions.Emails: Could  not load file or assembly
> 'System.ComponentModel, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the fil e
> specified.

```
using COMPANY.Functions.Emails;
using COMPANY.Functions.Emails.DataAccess;
using COMPANY.Functions.Emails.Services;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace COMPANY.Functions.Emails
{
    internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = BuildConfiguration(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath);
            builder.Services.AddScoped(_ => configuration);

            builder.Services.AddMediatR(config => config.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
            builder.Services.AddScoped(s =>
                new SqlConnectionFactory(configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomerConnection"),
                    s.GetRequiredService<CustomerIdContainer>()));
            builder.Services.AddScoped<Repository>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomerIdContainer>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomerSmtpSettingsFactory>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomerEmailClientFactory>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped(_ =>
                new BlobClientFactory(configuration.GetConnectionString("BlobStorageConnection")));
        }

        private IConfiguration BuildConfiguration(string applicationRootPath)
        {
            var config =
                new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(applicationRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();

            return config;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Installed `System.ComponentModel`, but the issue persists. Here is my csproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <LangVersion>11</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.143" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentEmail.Mailgun" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\COMPANY.Models\COMPANY.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

UPDATE:

I have updated my app to have Program.cs instead of FunctionsStartup but I still find the System.ComponentModel error

Program.cs

```
using COMPANY.Functions.Emails.DataAccess;
using COMPANY.Functions.Emails.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults();

builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration =>
{
    configuration
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
});

builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    services.AddMediatR(config => config.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Program>());
    services.AddScoped(s =>
        new SqlConnectionFactory(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CustomerConnection"),
            s.GetRequiredService<CustomerIdContainer>()));
    services.AddScoped<Repository>();
    services.AddScoped<CustomerIdContainer>();
    services.AddScoped<CustomerSmtpSettingsFactory>();
    services.AddScoped<CustomerEmailClientFactory>();
    services.AddScoped(_ =>
        new BlobClientFactory(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlobStorageConnection")));
});

var host = builder.Build();

host.Run();
```

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <LangVersion>11</LangVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.143" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentEmail.Mailgun" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.13.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />

  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\COMPANY.Models\COMPANY.Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: please provide your .csproj code.

Comment: I can see in the error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=7.0.0.0`. But the latest version of the package is [4.3.0](https://i.imgur.com/CQ3qyMd.png) and it supports .net 7. Install the latest version of the package `System.ComponentModel` and check.

Comment: Can you install `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` and check?

Comment: It did not help. I did some tests and if I wipe out all code from `Configure`, it stops complaining about that package and starts complaining about System.Net.Mail 7.0.0 on both functions.

Comment: @YehorAndrosov -  How does your `Program.cs` file look like?

Comment: @Harshitha this project doesn't have Program.cs - this is Azure functions app. I only have the class that extends FunctionsStartup

Comment: .Net 7 Funtion app has `Program.cs` file.As you have migrated from .NET 6 you may don't have it.

Comment: @Harshitha, yes, I see. Rider does not have .NET 7 template. Now I created .NET 7 function app in VS and copied over stucture - see new Update. Unfortunately, the error reproduces the same way as if I had the old FunctionsStartup

Comment: Ok..Will try to repro from my end and let you know.

Comment: @Harshitha I was able to find the solution. Please see my answer. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad that it is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the project by applying few changes - not exactly sure what helped.

local.settings.json - changed value "Values:FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" from "dotnet" to "dotnet-isolated"

Removed "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" and installed "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus". Because of this change I was also required to change from "FunctionName" attribute to "Function"

Cleaned bin/Debug folder as removing packages does not remove them from output folder and it seems to be loading all old assemblies.

Removed unnecessary configuration - invocations to AddJsonFile, AddEnvironmentVariables etc. I suppose, it picks all values automatically from these files

Answer (score 0):

The in-process execution model for Azure Functions v4 is not supported with .NET 7. Microsoft states they will only support it for LTS versions of .NET. As of this moment the only LTS version that supports in-process for Azure Functions v4 is .NET 6.

The LTS version of .NET 8 will also support it, but it will be the last version to do so. At this time the .NET 8 preview versions do not support the execution model either. See the [supported frameworks for the execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions) models for more information.

The best path forward is to migrate to the [isolated worker process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide), which works with >= .NET 6, as well as the Windows-only .NET Framework 4.8.